# Is there functions in coldfusion to get just 2 lines of text from a string?

Tags: function, string, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I know this works in other languages, but wanted to see if there is existing code/functions.

This string can be populated from numerous different queries, but they need to be all displayed the same way, same length etc.

I have a function, to control string length by word count, but I would prefer to make sure that I have at least 2 sentences or 2 lines of text at most.

Thanks

Comment: Where are your 'lines' being rendered?  It seems to me the easiest way is just to choose an arbitrary number of characters and play with it until you get it about right.

Comment: There's a sentence in Ulysses with 4300 words. As for lines, how long is a line, exactly? Pick a target number of characters, then add some logic to roll forward or backward to avoid individual word truncation, plus an ellipsis.

Comment: Well either 2 sentences if less than 2 lines being display in our search results page. This is for the search results, so that the description of items that are found isn't more than 2 lines. Which I have guestimated to be about 190 chars.

Comment: The goal is that, I want 2 lines of text, that hopefully have the keyword that is being searched for. This is a part of displaying search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar task at my job and you have to pick an arbitrary number, and it looks like you've chosen 190.  That being said, you can't just *hope* that the characters/words returned are relevant.  You have to **ensure** that they are if its something you care about, which is seems like you do looking at your comments.

Try to find the keyword in the string and use the mid() function to get a certain number of characters on either side of the keyword:

```
<cfscript>
  max_chars = 190;
  full_article = #the full article#;
  keyword_position = find(keyword, full_article);

  if( keyword_position != 0 ) {
    excerpt = mid(full_article, 
      keyword_position - max_chars / 2 - len(keyword_position) / 2,
      max_chars);
  }
</cfscript>
```

...or something like that.  I'll leave it to you to make sure that you're not trying to get characters before the start of the full_article, or after the end of it, and adding ellipses and stuff.

Comment: This works, very nice job. I wish this kind of code was in cflib.org because word based functions are hard to figure out and rare.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like [fullLeft](http://cflib.org/udf/fullLeft) or dig through the [other string manipulation](http://cflib.org/library/StrLib) UDFs at CFLib.  If you're looking for something more specific could you show us a comparable function in another language and we'd be better able to point you to something similar.

Comment: I should add that nothing you do is going to work 100% of the time if you don't have full control over the input string.  Plus modern fonts are not monospaced (each character does not take up the same horizontal space) so left("this is a sentence", 20) might render as desired while left("that was another sentence", 20) might not.  Also beware when trying to maintain word boundaries (as in the fullLeft udf above) because "fullLeft("this_is_a_sentence", 10)" might not behave as desired either.

Answer (score 0):

```
_TestString = "I know this works in other languages, but wanted to see if there is existing code/functions. This string can be populated from numerous different queries, but they need to be";
if ( len(_TestString) GT 190)
{
  _TestString = Left(_TestString,190) & "...";
}
```

That will output:

> I know this works in other languages, but wanted to see if there is existing code/functions. This string can be populated from numerous different queries, but they need to be all displayed t...

You probably don't want to do anything more than that, string manipulation can get expensive for no reason, you shouldn't waste processing on the display layer unless you have to.

Comment: but what happens when you do:  left('my short string', 190) & '...'?  you wouldn't want to add an ellipse unless there is truncation...

Comment: Todd, you're right.  I wasn't trying to give the full solution just help with my syntax, but I do agree.  Made edits per your comment.

Comment: I've used something similar in the past. It get's 190 character's correctly, but not necessarily the most relevant characters. But that's not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

CFLIB has plenty of string manipulation functions on offer.  You may find abbreviate() is useful, especially for search results: http://cflib.org/udf/abbreviate

```
<cfscript>
/**
* Abbreviates a given string to roughly the given length, stripping any tags, making sure the ending doesn't chop a word in two, and adding an ellipsis character at the end.
* Fix by Patrick McElhaney
* v3 by Ken Fricklas kenf@accessnet.net, takes care of too many spaces in text.
* 
* @param string      String to use. (Required)
* @param len      Length to use. (Required)
* @return Returns a string. 
* @author Gyrus (kenf@accessnet.netgyrus@norlonto.net) 
* @version 3, September 6, 2005 
*/
function abbreviate(string,len) {
    var newString = REReplace(string, "<[^>]*>", " ", "ALL");
    var lastSpace = 0;
    newString = REReplace(newString, " \s*", " ", "ALL");
    if lenn(newString) gt len) {
        newString = left(newString, len-2);
        lastSpace = find(" ", reverse(newString));
        lastSpace = len(newString) - lastSpace;
        newString = left(newString, lastSpace) & " &amp;##8230;";
    }    
    return newString;
}
</cfscript>
```